# detect a change to domain object

Tags: domain-driven-design, dns

There is an Entity:Customer and if the Customer changes his name ( via Web UI), the Customer Service must detect this change and send an email to Administrator.

Now should this responsibility be assigned to the Customer? Something like

c.HasChangedName(NewName); where c is a reference to the Customer

There could be other activities undertaken by the CustomerService based on such changes to the Customer entity. Email is just an example.

Comment: Sounds like logic you simply need to insert in your controller layer logic, not the entity.

Answer (score 4):

By my opinion, Customer aggregate root (I suppose it is an aggregate root and not an entity)  should publish CustomerNameChanged event in

```
customer.ChangeName(string newname)
```

method call.

You could look at [some implementation sample](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r/blob/master/SimpleCQRS/Domain.cs) in Greg Young's github repository.
Or if don't want to use event sourcing you could take a look at Udi Dahan's [post about domain events](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)

Comment: Absolutely, Customer is the aggregate root and thanks a ton for showing the light !!!!

Comment: Can you please point me to some more Domain Event based topics? This was one thing which I heard Eric Evans talking but never cared about its use. I would like to know more about the various scenarios where I can use it.

Comment: +1 Usage of domain events are robust way to deal with this problem.

Comment: I agree to answer above. Domain events let your aggregate root customer have the control of when to send notification. It also gives you a clean model and puts infra tech stift like email in infrastructure layer. You can check the dddsample.net that uses some domain events together with Asp.net mvc.

Comment: @GeorgeKT There are some posts from Greg Young (http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/04/11/what-is-a-domain-event/), Udi Dahan's another post (http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/25/domain-events-take-2/), Martin Fowler's article (http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html) and Mark Nijhof's post (http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/20/cqrs-the-domain-events/).